# What is the button Heero pushed when he and Relena first met in the beach?

Tags: gundam, gundam-wing

In episode 1 of Gundam Wing, after Wing Gundam was sent crashing down with a Leo on the bottom of the ocean, Relena sees Heero unconcious lying on the shore. When Heero woke up his helmet was removed and he immediately covered his face while asking Relena *"Did you see my face?"* as shown in this picture.

[image: Heero and Relena]

He then *punched* a button attached to his spacesuit and something on his chest exploded.

See in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qW4dY7w8Mz0) (sorry I just included Gundam Abridge-ning episode 1 dub parody of Gundam Wing)

What actually did Heero do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [wikia](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Heero_Yuy) the suit had a built in suicide bomb but it was damaged by the salt water. I would guess that this is to prevent the pilots from being captured. This would be similar to fighter pilots during [War](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_pill) time using cyanid pills to keep from being interrogated for delicate information.

> Washing up on the beach, Heero's unconscious body was found by Relena and, in an attempt to kill himself, pounded his chest detonator triggering the flight suit's built-in suicide bomb. However, the saltwater damaged the explosive which caused only his detonator to fire, knocking Heero over.